# Session data lost after a HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: django, django-sessions

I have this redirect view that sets session variables. But it's as if the session is `flush`ed before the view that is being redirected to is called, as the whole session is empty there.

(Btw, this is the real code, I've cut stuff to find the cause but still can't find it).

```
class ActivateUserView(RedirectView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # activates user and redirects to listing
        listing = Listing.objects.get(id=2)
        request.session['test'] = 'icle'
        print("Session set to: ", request.session.get('test', "Nothing!"))
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('listing-detail', kwargs={'pk': listing_pk, 'slug': listing.slug}))
```

The view the above is redirected to:

```
class ListingDetailView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "frontend/detail.html"

    @method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie)
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Session data: ", request.session.get('test', "Nothing!"))
        return super(ListingDetailView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

In the console, I get:

```
Session set to:  icle 
Session data:  Nothing!
```

I've checked with django-debug-toolbar, raising Exceptions here and there, and somewhere between the redirect call and the view, all session data is deleted.

Comment: Since you're modifying a top level session key, django should see that and save the session off, so something's not right... Can you try both of these independently to see if it makes any difference? 1. call request.session.save() manually. 2. After setting the 'test' value, set `request.session.modified = True`. Note that these _shouldn't_ be final solutions, I'm just curious if that changes the behavior.

Comment: Thanks, but I found it... I had set `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE` to True, but in development mode I'm not using https... I'll answer my question and leave it to the mods if it needs to be deleted instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE` to False (in my dev settings) solved the issue. I was using a local, non-https dev environment.

Comment: For a dev env closer to production it is best practice to use https also locally. The django-extensions package provides runserver_plus (https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runserver_plus.html) which supports https and can automatically generate self-signed certificates.