# Django session cookie is changed to "" and expiration date of 1970

Tags: python, django, cookies

I have a problem with the cookies of a session logged into a web with Django. The session is started correctly and when I send request with the session cookie, the server response overwrites the session cookie with "" and sets the expiration date to January 1, 1970.

This is something that happens completely randomly. I have checked the database and the session is stored. If I change the cookie that it gives me for the one that the login should have, it is done correctly.

Does anyone know what could be happening?

Comment: January 1 1970 is the start date for unix time. its understandable that empty date string means 1 Jan 1970.  There may be problem in the server about setting expiration date

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue. Please let me know how did you solve this issue. I would really appreciate your help. I am struggling with this issue from many days

Answer (score 0):

If you are running django on a non-https server, you need to set `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False` in settings.py. Otherwise your session data might be lost as stated in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50873880/session-data-lost-after-a-httpresponseredirect)

You can check the session cookie in your view by using: `request.COOKIES.get('sessionid')`.

Comment: That's not it. `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=False` is the default. Unfortunately I cannot reproduce the problem with expiration date 1970 anymore, but when using `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=True` via http, Django still sends the cookie (with the correct expiration date). It is the _browser_ that ignores/does not store it.

Comment: Did you test this with a different browser? Which browser are you using? Can you provide the view in which this problem is occurring?

Answer (score 0):

**If anyone is having similar issues on users being logged out (their session cookie being deleted):**

My problem was, I was using django-channels and calling `logout` in the `disconnect` method of my consumer. Websocket connections can close quite randomly, therefore I was experiencing random user logouts as well.